# problems with parsing a text file in Java

Tags: java

I have looked at all the links and cannot seem to get what I am looking for. I have a text file I need to read in. First the text file format:

```
3 STL NY Chi //all on one line
STL NY 575 //on its own line
NY Chi 550 //on its own line
STL Chi 225 //on its own line
```

I need to read the int into an int variable, say we call it count. Then the actual cities on that same line into an array. The next lines need to read into an array to where the mileage is associated with the array, such as [STL NY]=575. I can only use arrays. No hash tables, list, stacks or queues. Here is what I got so far and honestly it isn't much. I could really use some help for I am pretty stumped on the "howto" on this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class P3 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static int count;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        FileInputStream dataFile = new FileInputStream("Data.txt");
        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataFile));

        String line = br.readLine();

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println ("Unable to open file");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
  }
}
```

---

I think I'm getting there, but I am getting an error code of: "non-static variable cities cannot be referenced from a static context." I am trying to test my code by printing. Can anyone help me with this printing? I would like to see what is in the arrays to make sure I did it correctly. Here is my code:

```
package p3;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



class citiesDist {
    String cityOne;
    String cityTwo;
    int miles;
}

class city {
    String cityName;
    int numberLinks;
    citiesDist[] citiesDists;
}

public class P3 {

    city[] cities;

    void initCity(int len) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            cities[i] = new city();
        }
    }

    void initCitiesDist (int index, int len) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            cities[index].citiesDists[i] = new citiesDist();
        }
    }

    void parseFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException { 
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Data.txt"); 
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); 

        int numberCities = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        cities = new city[numberCities];
        initCity(numberCities);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberCities; i++) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            int numberLink = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[1]);
            cities[i].cityName = line.split(" ")[0];
            cities[i].numberLinks = numberLink;
            initCitiesDist (i, numberLink);

            for (int j = 0; j < numberLink; j++){
                line = br.readLine();
                cities[i].citiesDists[j].cityOne = line.split(" ")[0];
                cities[i].citiesDists[j].cityTwo = line.split(" ")[1];
                cities[i].citiesDists[j].miles = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[2]);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("city" + cities.city);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) *"I have looked at all the links"* You've looked at about 37.4 million pages returned for "parse text java"?  Wow, you've been busy.  But instead of trying to 'look at' millions, try 'reading' the first 10. 2) What is your question?

Comment: As a starting point I'd suggest looking at the API for `String` to see how you can extract the information you want from each line of the file. Have you actually tried anything beyond what you've posted here?

Comment: Seriously Andrew? Was that called for? I love how people that have been doing this for a while forget where they started.

Comment: milkplusvellocet the API really did not say much about splitting up a text file as it is being read in with the exception of regular expressions. Yes I did try using scanner and got a little of it done. Interesting enough, my book does not explain show any kind of example of getting it into an array.

Comment: 1) milkplusvellocet is pointing you in the right direction. Do a search on splitting strings by spaces and you'll find more than one example. 2) Programming is not a spectator sport. You'll get better responses by trying something and asking for help rather than saying you've read something that wasn't illuminating and trying nothing.

Comment: karakuricoder sure it is and I have been on this thing since this morning. I have tried several things. I usually try not to post for the simple reason of being "battered." I was/am just stumped on this one.

Comment: But what have you tried? From the code you've posted it looks like you haven't tried anything beyond reading the first line of the file into a `String`. Share what you've attempted and we'll be happy to help. There's also a very good answer from @Makoto below which should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ever stumped on code, don't think about the programming language; it only serves to further muddle your logic.  (Separate the algorithm from the language.)  When you have a clear idea of what you want to accomplish, add your language in (insofar as, "how do I accomplish *this* particular task?").

## Ultimate Goal

From your design, your goal is to have a graph relating the distances between each city.  It would appear something like this:

```
     [STL][NY] [Chi]
[STL][0]  [575][25]
[NY] [575][0]  [550]
[Chi][25] [550][0]
```

This isn't too terribly difficult to accomplish, in terms of the file input and the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

## First Steps

You have to extract the dimensions of your graph (which is a 3 by 3).  This is provided for you in the first line of your input file.  Getting an integer from a `Scanner` with a `File` in it isn't too difficult, just make sure you have the proper classes imported, as well as the proper error handling (either `try...catch` or throwing the exception).

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
```

You'll need two arrays - one for the cities, and one for the distances themselves.  We don't know how large they are (you *never* assume the data in a file, you just assume the form of the data), so we have to get that from the file itself.  Luckily, we are given an integer followed by the cities themselves.  We will read this integer once and use it in multiple different locations.

```
String[] cities = new String[sc.nextInt()];
int[][] distances = new int[cities.length][cities.length];
for(int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    // Surely there's a method in Scanner that returns String that reads the _next_ token...
}
```

## The Exercise to the Reader

You now have your data structure set up and ready to go.  What you would need to do from here is bridge the gap between the cities array and distances array.  Consider the order in which they arrived in the file, and the order in which we're encountering them.  You would be well-served with some methodology or way to answer the question, 'Which came first - STL or NY?'

Give it a whirl and see if you can get further.

Comment: Ok, I think I might have something here, but I am getting an error code of: "non-static variable cities cannot be referenced from a static context" I am trying to test my code.